# Could not open socket: stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to tcp://92.204.134.154:587

Tags: email, server, smtp, connectivity

I transfer my site to a dedicated server from GoDaddy

When I lost my password to the back admin I could not receive an email to reset it

When I try to reset my password from my admin account

It says  Could not open socket: stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to tcp://92.204.134.154:587 (Connection refused)

Please Help

JewelryNest

Comment: This is a question for godaddy's or your new hoster's support team. Stackoverflow is for programming questions only. Please avoid tags like `smtp` that are unrelated to your question. See [ask].

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.